# Reusing compiled regex in re.search

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.5

I stumbled upon the following code:

```
import re 

regex_compiled = re.compile('\d{2}-\d{3,5}')

res = re.search(regex_compiled, '12-9876')
```

I was under impression that `re.search` attempts to compile the first parameter which is already compiled so it should error or `regex_compiled.__repr__()` or `regex_compiled.__str__()`  should be called just before a repeated attempt to compile it!

Just to be sure I compared it with `regex_compiled.search(...`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("import re; regex_compiled = re.compile('\d{2}-\d{3,5}');     res = re.search(regex_compiled, '12-9876')")
1.3797054840251803

>>> timeit("import re; regex_compiled = re.compile('\d{2}-\d{3,5}');     res = regex_compiled.search('12-9876')")
0.7649686150252819
>>>
```

I am very puzzled from where so substantial difference comes from given that debugging into `re.search` (in both CPython v. 2 and v. 3) shows that the *compiled* pattern is reused! I hope someone can help shed some light on this.

Execution environment: Ubuntu 16.04, 64b

Comment: I don't know this is a duplicate. I am fully aware about the caching mechanism and that is why I stumbled on the difference in the timing which is substantial. That difference bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re._compile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/05cb728d68a278d11466f9a6c8258d914135c96c/Lib/re.py#L277) first checks if the argument is cached, and then if it's already compiled. So when you pass a compiled pattern to `re.whatever` it wastes some time computing and looking up a cache key which actually is never going to match. Repring the pattern and `OrderedDict` lookups are heavy operations that seem to explain the discrepancy you're observing.

A possible rationale for this behaviour is that `_compile` is optimized for string patterns, which is its primary use case, and designed to return a cache hit as soon as possible.

Here are some timings:

```
from time import time
import re
import sys

print(sys.version)

pat = '\d{2}-\d{3,5}'
loops = 1000000

re.purge()

t = time()
for _ in range(loops):
    re._compile(pat, 0)
print('compile string  ', time() - t)

re.purge()

rc = re._compile(pat, 0)
t = time()
for _ in range(loops):
    re._compile(rc, 0)
print('compile compiled', time() - t)
```

Results:

```
$ python3 test.py
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
compile string   0.5387749671936035
compile compiled 0.7378756999969482

$ python2 test.py
2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
('compile string  ', 0.5074479579925537)
('compile compiled', 1.3561439514160156)
```